# Relative path on a Mac

Tags: macos

It may be me, or it might be my Mac Book Pro, 10.8.5, Safari 6.0.5. I cannot use a relative path in my HTML.
I have folder A. Within folder A I have an images folder; my index.html code is also in folder A. Yet I code:

```
<img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="Something" />
```

and I get the blue square with the white question mark; image not found.
If I'm on a Windows machine, I have no problem with a relative path.
If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: it does of course work, perhaps you could give us an example.

Comment: I don't know what you want an example of.

Comment: This is my img src. body>
    <div id="container">
    
        <div id="header">file:///Users/janedoe/CGT136as/week-07hw/website/images/lily-pads.jpg" alt="Admin Extraordinaire"  />           
   <!-- another img class MAY GO HERE. but for now, nothing -->   
        </div><!--/#header-->

Comment: Sorry about that. I keep hitting enter. body>
    <div id="container">
    
        <div id="header">file:///Users/janedoe/CGT136as/week-07hw/website/images/lily-pads.jpg" alt="Admin Extraordinaire"  />           
   <!-- another img class MAY GO HERE. but for now, nothing -->   
        </div><!--/#header--> I want to be able to code images/lily-pads.jpg. thank u

Comment: Post the body of your HTML in an edit to your question rather than the comments. It looks like a typo before `file://` for one thing.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Relative paths *should* work just fine. I just tested your example, and the image loaded without issue.

Why does it work on my Mac, and not yours?

Things to try:

1. Check your file and folder names carefully for ***typos***
2. Make sure ***file extensions*** are not hidden ( *Finder > Preferences > Advanced > Show all filename extensions* )? Maybe your jpeg is actually 'photo.jpg.jpg'
3. ***Reload*** the page in Safari ( *Shift + Click on the refresh button* )
4. Test with an ***alternate jpeg*** image to rule out issues with the file system.